# Meaning of draft status?

Tags: journals, peer-review

I would like to ask a question about the meaning of the status "Draft" of my submitted article in a Taylor and Francis journal?

Comment: See https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55665/72855

Comment: Although I agree that the linked question is relevant, it doesn't once mention the word 'draft', so I disagree that it answers OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you pressed the "submit" button? Usually it is a draft before submission.

Otherwise it might mean that some sort of manual approval of an admin person of the journal is needed before the submission is further processed (e.g. it is not "fully" sumitted until they have checked that you are within a certain wordcount/format/etc).